# How to split resolvers for Query type in Hot Chocolate

Tags: graphql, hotchocolate

I am trying to achieve a standard GraphQL implementation, using the Hot Chocolate library for .net core, where the resolvers for reading data belong to the root Query object.
Like this:

```
{
  Query {
    GetTodo {
      Id
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I made trying to follow the documentation, but it doesn't work as I expect:

**startup.cs**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ChocodotContext>();
            services.AddGraphQL(
                SchemaBuilder.New()
                .AddQueryType<QueryType>()
                .BindResolver<TodoQueries>()
                .Create()
            );
        }
```

**Query.cs**

```
using HotChocolate.Types;

namespace Queries
{
    public class QueryType : ObjectType
    {
        protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor descriptor)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

**TodoQueries.cs**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HotChocolate;
using HotChocolate.Types;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;
using Models;

namespace Queries
{
    [GraphQLResolverOf(typeof(Todo))]
    [GraphQLResolverOf("Query")]
    public class TodoQueries
    {
        public async Task<Todo> GetTodo([Service] ChocodotContext dbContext) {
            return await dbContext.Todos.FirstAsync();
        }        
    }

    public class TodoQueryType : ObjectType<TodoQueries> {
        
    }
}
```

What am I not getting right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change it a little:

```
query {
  todo {
    id
  }
}
```

**startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ChocodotContext>();
    services.AddGraphQL(serviceProvider =>
        SchemaBuilder.New()
            .AddServices(serviceProvider)
            .AddQueryType<Query>()
            .AddType<TodoQueries>()
            .Create()
    );
}
```

**Query.cs**

```
using HotChocolate.Types;

namespace Queries
{
    public class Query
    {

    }
}
```

**TodoQueries.cs**

```
[ExtendObjectType(Name = "Query")]
public class TodoQueries
{
    // Side note, no need for async/await while it returns Task<>
    //
    public Task<Todo> GetTodo([Service] ChocodotContext dbContext) {
        return dbContext.Todos.FirstAsync();
    }        
}
```

Tested with HotChocolate 10.5.2

Source of solution - ChilliCream Blog, HotChocolate 10.3.0 article, [TypeAttributes](https://chillicream.com/blog/2019/12/26/hotchocolate-10.3.0#type-attributes) section.